# ios find the user account by iap screenshot

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In our app, each user has an account. They can buy some product via ios iap. Sometimes, some user forget their account id, and they can only provide a screenshot of their purchase. 
The question is, is there some way to find their id by the screenshot and what should i do?

Comment: Hey, @edolphin Bind each user account with a product which they buy i.e. maintain a table for history which user is buying what so it will be easy for you track easily.

Comment: @PrakashTripathi but, each product can be bought by any one, so only with the product cannot find a unique user id

Comment: You could expose some user identifier in the app settings that users can reference for support type tickets. I assume that's what this is for?

Comment: @enc_life This could be a choice, but if the user has uninstalled the app, and reinstalled again, this won't work anymore. So, if it's definitely no way by the iap screenshot, i'll pick you suggestion.

Comment: If you don't have a login system, you can generate a random UUID and store it in the Keychain which should be persisted across installs.

Comment: @enc_life You'v inspired me. The keychain is a great solution. Thanks a lot.